# modulus of a complex number and module of a function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $a,r\in\Bbb R^*_+$.

I choose as definition of complex logarithm, the one defined by  $\log(z)=\log(|z|)+i\theta$ with $z=|z|e^{i\theta}$ et $\theta\in\,]-\pi,\pi[$.

So $(ir)^{ia}=e^{ia\ln(ir)}=e^{ia(\ln(r)+i{\pi\over2}})=e^{ia(\ln(r)}e^{-a\pi\over2}$.
And hence the  modulus of $(ir)^{ia}$ is $e^{-a\pi\over2}$. Is it true?

On the other hand if
$W_{\lambda,\mu}(z)\sim\mathrm{e}^{-z/2}z^\lambda$

as $|z|\to\infty$. We have

$$W_{ia,\mu}(ir)\sim\mathrm{e}^{-ir/2}(ir)^{ia}$$?

Can we say $$|W_{ia,\mu}(ir)|\sim e^{-a\pi\over2}$$

Comment: I think by module you mean modulus.

Comment: Yeah. Modulus of $|a+ib|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ with $a,b\in\Bbb{R}$.